# Postman use refresh_token from collection auth

Tags: postman

I'm using the Authorization-Tab from a collection to obtain my tokens from keycloak.
I gave the token a name "acme_Token".
All child-requests are using inherit auth from parent. All is working well.
But now I came to the logout-request. There the clientId and the refresh_token are needed to logout the current user.
The clientId is no problem because it is a collection-variable, but I can't figure out how to get the refresh_token from the parent (collection-node).
I tried something as:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("refresh_token", jsonData.refresh_token);
```

On the Tests-Tab of the collection.

I also tried to read the named "acme_Token", but I can't get it.

How can I use the actual refresh_token (automatic refresh) of the collection-node in a child-request?

Answer (score 0):

To access the `refresh_token` value from the parent collection in a child request, you can use the `pm.collectionVariables.get()` function in the Pre-request Script of the child request:

1. In the parent request, save the `refresh_token` value as a collection variable using the following script in the Tests tab:

```js
pm.collectionVariables.set("refresh_token", pm.response.json().refresh_token);
```

2. In the child request, add the following script to the Pre-request Script tab:

```js
var refresh_token = pm.collectionVariables.get("refresh_token");
pm.variables.set("refresh_token", refresh_token);
```

This will retrieve the `refresh_token` value from the parent collection's variables and set it as a variable in the child request's scope. You can then use the `{{refresh_token}}` variable in the child request's Authorization header.

Note: Make sure that the child request is using the same authorization type as the parent request and that the token name is the same in both requests.

Comment: Hi Christian, oh I know this way, but I didn't have a parent request. I want to use the authorization tab from the collection with outh2. There I activate Auto refresh token. Now I want to use the latest refresh_token in a request under this collection to perform a logout where the refresh_token is used.